# Calling a function in setInterval gives error in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a React Native app where I'm trying to call a function in setInterval to re-render component in every three seconds. But when I put the function in setInterval it returns the error `this.refreshData() is not a function`. Here's the code for this I'm having:

```js
 refreshData = async()=> {
  await fetch('https://myapi', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ tableData1: response.First })
        this.setState({ tableData2: response.Special })
        this.setState({ tableData3: response.Consolidation })
      })
  }
  
    componentWillMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
      var today = new Date()
      var time = today.getHours()
      console.log(today.getMinutes())
      var weekDay = today.getDay()
      if ((time >= 22) && (time <= 23 )){
       if(today.getMinutes()<=30){
    
      setInterval(function() {
        this.refreshData()
        }, 3000);
    }
    });
  }
```

How this error can be resolved?

Comment: corrected that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**arrow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function.

Try this example:

```js
function refreshData(){
    console.log("called");
}
setInterval(() => {
    this.refreshData();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: the error is gone but now the function gets called only once when its supposed to be called after each 3 seconds. @SaurabhAgrawal

Comment: @TanmoySarker use setTimeInterval ?

Comment: @TanmoySarker You need then setInterval not setTimeout. setInterval runs every 3 seconds

Comment: Yes.That was a typo. I am using setInterval but after using arrow function it is being run only once not after each three seconds. @ShubhamVerma

Comment: @TanmoySarker updated  my answer now check it's keep calling after 3 seconds.

Comment: No still the same. @SaurabhAgrawal

Answer (score 1):

Either bind the setTimeout/setInterval function or use Arrow function i.e

```
setTimeout(function() { //or setInterval(whatever you need to use)
        this.refreshData()
        }, 3000);
    }
 }).bind(this);
```

or

```
setTimeout(() => { //or setInterval(whatever you need to use)
    this.refreshData();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: @TanmoySarker I have made code sandbox for your reference. Please check it : https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-rhodes-2nx1x